# Registers ” vs @

Tags: register

Ok I must have missed something vital here. Can someone please tell me what the difference between using `"a` and `@a` is? All I know is that `@` is used together with `:let` and e.g. `:echo` and `"` is used when pasting.

However I find no sources that explains the difference and what the prefixes mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note: all of the following information (and much more) can be found using `:help @`, `:help "`, `:help let-@`, and `:help expr-register`

- `"ap`,`"ad`, &c.: use register `a` in a put from or delete to.
- `@a`: replay the contents of register `a` as a sequence of normal commands
- `:let @a = 'string'`: assign a string to register a.

Now, there is likely some confusion because `@` and `"` are occasionally interchangeable:

- `""p`, `"@p`, `p`: put from register `"`, this is called the "unnamed register," but in fact it has at least two names, `"` and `@`.
- `@"`: replay the contents of register `"` as a normal command (this is rarely done).
- `@@`: replay the previously used `@{reg}`.

Then, there are the `let` and expression usages:

- `:let @" = 'string'`: `let @@ = 'string'`: assign a string to register `"`.
- `:echo @@`, `:echo @"`: echo the value of register `"`
- `:echo @`: also echo the value of register `"`.
- `:echo "@`, `:echo "`: syntax error.

Finally, you can execute registers as an ex command (i.e., cmdline mode),

- `:@a`: execute contents of register `a` as an ex command.
- `:@:`: execute the previous command line
- `:@@`: execute the previous `:@{reg}`.

Comment: You might add `:@a` : apply the contents of register `a` as Ex command(s).

Comment: @BLayer Good point, although I can't remember the last time I needed to use them

Comment: Cool. I actually use it quite a bit. For instance, I might be doing some quick hacking on a function or mapping...make a change, yank it (`yap` or `yy` or whatever) and load/reload with `:@0`.